# Multiple validations on React PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript, react-proptypes

Is there a way to have multiple validations on a single prop using `React.PropTypes`. specifically want to blend a custom validation and a stock validation.

I have two props, an object `options`, and a string `value`. i want to check that `props.value` is a string but also a key on the object. using coffeescript this looks like:

```
propTypes:
  options: React.PropTypes.Object.isRequired
  value: (props, propName, componentName) ->
    unless props[propName] of props.options
      new Error('my custom message')
```

this works great, but i also want to ensure that my value is a string type. I'm sure i can manually stick in that validation in the custom function no problem, but ideally, i'd just like to use `React.PropTypes.string.isRequired`. ive tried just putting it in the custom function and executing it but that did not work. the following didn't work either:

```
  value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired && (props, propName, componentName) ->
    unless props[propName] of props.options
      new Error('my custom message')
```

is there a way to get this working using reacts built in validator, or is rewriting it in my function the only option?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Reusable Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) page in the docs:

```
You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error
// object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this
// won't work inside `oneOfType`.
customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
    return new Error('Validation failed!');
  }
}
```

So a propType returns nothing or an error object. We can write a 'all' function which takes two propTypes and merges the result.

```
const allPropTypes = (...types) => (...args) => {
  const errors = types.map((type) => type(...args)).filter(Boolean);

  // no errors? cool!
  if (errors.length === 0) return;

  // collect the messages and join them together
  const message = errors.map((e) => e.message).join('\n');
  return new Error(message);
};
```

Then you can use this to assert against multiple propTypes.

```
propTypes = {
  foo: allPropTypes(
    PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    (props, propName, componentName) => props.options && props.options[props[propName]] 
      ? undefined
      : new Error(
          `${componentName}: expected prop ${propName}="${prop[propName]}"` 
          + `to be a key of prop "options" `
          + `(one of ${Object.keys(props.options).join(', ')})`
        )
  )
}
```

Note: none of this is tested, but no syntax errors! You can compile it to es3 with babel, or convert it to CS by hand.

Comment: I'm aware i can just keep adding things to my custom validation. it could probably get by by doing `return new Error('msg') unless typeof props[propName] == 'string'`, but I'm asking if theres a more formal way that react provides (ie. still being able to use `React.PropTypes.string.isRequired`) because its much more apparent as to what is going on

Comment: @PhilVarg you need to create your own proptype. None of the built in propTypes do any cross prop checks as far as I know. You can put it in a module somewhere and import it with a nice name, and even have the `options` part be dynamic, e.g. `foo: isKeyOfProp('options')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [this](http://www.ian-thomas.net/custom-proptype-validation-with-react/) link, Ian Thomas explains the use of a createChainableTypeChecker method which is in react but not exported as part of propTypes module. The article has a clear explanation of how you can use the same code to chain validation calls:

```
function createChainableTypeChecker(validate) {  
  function checkType(isRequired, props, propName, componentName, location) {
    componentName = componentName || ANONYMOUS;
    if (props[propName] == null) {
      var locationName = ReactPropTypeLocationNames[location];
      if (isRequired) {
        return new Error(
          ("Required " + locationName + " `" + propName + "` was not specified in ") +
          ("`" + componentName + "`.")
        );
      }
      return null;
    } else {
      return validate(props, propName, componentName, location);
    }
  }

  var chainedCheckType = checkType.bind(null, false);
  chainedCheckType.isRequired = checkType.bind(null, true);

  return chainedCheckType;
}
```

Comment: Where can I get ReactPropTypeLocationNames?